# Dash Plotly: What is the best way to plot an image grid of (n_rows, n_cols) images? n_rows needs to be changeable by a user

Tags: python, image, plotly-dash

I am having trouble plotting a grid of images in dash. In particular, I want to create a grid of n_rows x n_cols, where n_cols can be anywhere between 5 and 10 and n_rows need to be user specified. Every image is the same size.

So far, I have used px.imshow() with the facet_col option. However, for a large number of images the images get very small.

I have used plotly.subplots.make_subplots() directly, however, when I change n_rows within the app the images do not stay in their respective positions and get moved around. In particular, when I first choose to plot 5 images beneath each other, the plot will look fine, [plotting five images closely together (chosen first)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBcBi.png). However, when the user subsequently chooses to plot 2 points,
[the images will be plotted in the same space the five images were](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z9nG.png). Similarly, when the user first chooses to plot 2 images the image looks fine. [Subsequently, when the user plots 5 images, they all get messed up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nnPI.png)

See the following code to reproduce:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash.exceptions
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


def create_fig(n_rows):
    fig = make_subplots(n_rows, 1)

    for i in range(n_rows):
        fig.add_trace(go.Image(z=np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(60, 60, 3))), i+1, j)

    fig.update_layout(autosize=True,
                      width=100,
                      height=n_rows*100,
                      margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0)
                      )
    return fig


def create_fig_using_pximshow(n_rows):
    images = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(n_rows, 60, 60, 3))
    fig = px.imshow(images, facet_col=0, facet_col_wrap=1, facet_row_spacing=0.3/n_rows)

    fig.update_layout(autosize=True,
                      width=100,
                      height=n_rows*100,
                      margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0)
                      )
    return fig


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(id='graph', style={'overflow':'scroll'}),
     dcc.Input(value=0, id='input', type='number')])


@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'), Input('input', 'value'))
def create_graph(n_rows):
    if n_rows == 0:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate("Prevent update")
    else:
        if n_rows is not None:

            return create_fig(int(n_rows))
            # return create_fig_using_pximshow(int(n_rows))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note that changing go.Image to go.Scatter makes the code work and the dashboard graph adapt to the amount of rows present.
Is there a better/easier way to plot a grid of images?

Comment: `matplotlib` uses `subplots` which offers this....

Comment: *"for a large number of images the images get very small"*....  what do you expect ?  if the area is finite and `n` and `m` are large then the images **must** be small to be able to fit inside the area...

Comment: I understand, however, it is not possible to use matplotlib within a dash dashboard. 

Moreover, even when I increase the figure size and let it overflow the window size, creating an ‘infinite’ area, the images still cluster to a small part of the window

Comment: interesting...  maybe you can post an example of what you have done so far in that respect:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited my question to add a minimal working example that should reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I played around with your example code, and I agree that the make_subplots approach has some janky behaviour. Maybe because of the Image size being fixed and then trying to fit into the Dash figure size? Not quite sure what's going on. I wonder if the imgshow approach might be a better way to go. Are you able to also post the code for that?

Comment: also, it actually is possible to embed matplotlib plots. you can base64 encode the exported image and set it to the src attribute of an <image> element as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56932297/77533, or you can use the dash-alternative-viz library: https://github.com/plotly/dash-alternative-viz/blob/fd2f85fd712b4667e78c5ab8d28044bf464fdf63/usage.py#L137-L141

Comment: I have added the px.imshow() functionality, which sadly has the same problem.

Comment: I know it is possible to embed matplotlib plots, however, I get a warning not to use it (see link you sent). Moreover, I tried it and embedding the image cannot overflow the screen like plotly images can. Therefore, rendering it useless if n_rows gets big.